# How do I change values in a dictionary in one key?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, I have a key = name. Within name, there's birthday, age, and phone number. I would only like to change say birthday but keep the rest. And I'm trying to use an existing file that have the names already.

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: What kind of object / structure is `name`? A string? A list?

Comment: As far as what can and cannot be changed I think the vocabulary Mutable is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to use a **tuple** as a key the syntax would be

```
d[(name, phoneNumber)] = birthday
```

as far as using values in a pre-existing file you will need the **open** method.

```
file = open("fileName.csv",r) # assuming that you have a file of comma separated values 
text = file.read()
           .split("\n")
peps = [p.split(",") for p in text]
dictionary = {}
for p in peps:
    d[(p[column of name] , p[col# for phone number)]]=p[#Bday]
```

Roughly. There are several types of collections in python, {}, [], (), hash and set. I would recommend that you read up on each [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)